# How to compute percentage within groups

Tags: r, dplyr

In a dataset including employees by department, I am trying to calculate the total employee count in each department and job role divided by the total number of employees in either female or male groups.

The final result should be divided up horizontally by female and male. Under both female and male, there are three different departments listed. Vertically, I have four different job roles listed. Each cell holds a value of the total percent.

For example, if there's a total of 100 females and four people in the maternity department AND nurse role, that particular cell will display 4%.

What am I doing incorrectly to summarize data into this format?

My current code:

```
library(dplyr)

attr_per <- heatmap_data %>% 
  group_by(Department, JobRole, Gender) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = sum(Attrition == "Yes")/n()) %>% 
  summarize(Department, JobRole, Gender, Percent)
```

The ultimate goal is to use this data to make a heatmap.

Comment: Try `attr_per <- heatmap_data %>%  group_by(Department, JobRole, Gender) %>% summarise(Percent = sum(Attrition == "Yes") / n())`.

Comment: *"100 females and four people"* ... are females not people?

Comment: Please provide the output from `dput(head(heatmap_data))`, it'll help inform what you are starting with. Can you also include an explicit example of what the output should be?

Answer (score 0):

Summarize your counts, then mutate as a percentage.

You may want to make Attrition a calculated value like
`gorup_by(..., Attrition = Attrition == "yes")`

```
library(dplyr)
heatmap_data |>
  group_by(Department, JobRole, Category, Attrition) |>
  summarise(count = n()) |>
  # may want to reset the grouping variables here
  mutate(Percent = count/sum(count))
```